# Why am i getting ValueError: too many values to unpack -Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-s3

The following code is throwing a ValueError: too many values to unpack

```
if remote_folder is not None:
            for directory_name, files in os.walk(file_path):
                for filename in files:
                    remote_folder.key = os.path.join(
                        remote_file_path,
                        directory_name,
                        filename)
                    file_size_uploaded = remote_folder.set_contents_from_filename(  # noqa
                        os.path.join(directory_name, filename), replace=True)
            return False if file_size_uploaded == 0 else True
```

This method is trying to upload files to an S3 Bucket

Can anyone explain why and how to avoid?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This:

```
for directory_name, files in os.walk(file_path):
```

os.walk returns 3-tuples, so when trying to assign 3-tuple to 2-tuple your exception raises.

Use:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(file_path):
```

docs on `os.walk`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk

Comment: what about my directory_name

Comment: should it be :
for root, directory_name, files in os.walk(file_path):

Comment: no, dirs is list of directories in root directory. So for you basically it should be: `for directory_name, dirs, files in os.walk(file_path):`

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation for [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk), it yields a 3-tuple. With

`for directory_name, files in os.walk(file_path):`

you are trying to unpack a 3-tuple into 2 variables , so there are "too many values to unpack". You'll need to add a third variable to that line, then your code should run.

Answer (score 1):

Since os.walk returns a 3-tuple and that you don't seem to have any use for dirnames, you could, instead of your original `for directory_name, files in os.walk(file_path):`, do the following:

This:

```
# This style makes it clear that you aren't using the 
# second (dirnames) variable.
for directory_name, _, files in os.walk(file_path):
```

or:

```
# This slices the part that you need
for directory_name, files in os.walk(file_path)[::2]:
```

It makes it more explicit that you *aren't using* dirnames at all.

Comment: Your second code variant yields an error:
'generator' object is not subscriptable